# Android toolbar navigation with Close and Arrow button

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to make a toolbar navigation like this.

When I create my activity, I inflate a fragment and draw a close button on my toolbar. But, if user opens another fragment, shows the back arrow... But on this source, it only shows close button.

Here is my `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            int stackHeight = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (stackHeight > 0) {
                if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (findViewById(R.id.container_initial) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(), new LoginFragment(), R.id.container_initial);
    }
}
```

If i remove this code, work the part of back arrow button, but dont show the close button...

```
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white);
    }
```

Comment: May bee you show arrow button elsewhere? Take in mind that you can use ToolBar not treating it as ActionBar but as a normal view placed on top of the screen

Comment: Try to use icon in menu and give "if room" like this you get other side whichever icon you want

Comment: <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="@string/btn_sign_out"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

Answer (score 0):

try in menu like this but by this you get close in place of menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/Updatetimetable"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Update"
    android:icon="@drawable/updatepopup"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/viewalert"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="View alert"
    android:icon="@drawable/alertcards"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the toolbar is in the activity layout. create a setter method for the icon in activity & call it in the fragment to change it.

```
void setIcon(){
..
}

onBackPressed(){
if(fragment visible) getsupportfragmentmanger.begintranscation().close
else super.onbackprsesed
}
```

Comment: My toolbar is on activity... But i didn't understand the code... Could you explain better?

Comment: create a setIcon() method in your activty & call it from the fragment to change the icon to back arrow. & override onbackpressed() method in your activity to check if the fragment is visible. If the fragment is visible close it.